# GTM fires my tags, but preview and debug doesn't show events and Datalayer variables

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

we have 2 domains with exactly the same implementation. One of them works perfectly, but in the second one I can't see any data in preview and debug mode. The strange thing is, all tags fire and work properly. Probably something is blocking debug mode in my browser.

- I tried to delete the cache and cookies
- i used different types of browsers
- i do not use adblock
- console doesn't show anything suspicious.

I suppose it is something with GTM consent, but could anyone please help me understand why it is happening? Any advice you could give would be much appreciated. Thank you.

[GTM Preview and debug mode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzTFh.png)

[GTM Consent screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiVG8.png)

[Enhance ecommerce datalayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdEy1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not seen this before.

But might need to advice that each domain and website should have it's own GTM container.

maybe you can try to create a new container to see this issue is still happening.

---

For the ProductDetail dataLayer

Try to use these at first.

Then push your event.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
```